# If $A$ is compact set then is the set of accumulation points $A'$ necessarily compact too?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $A$ be a compact subset of topological space $X$ and $A$' it's derived set. Is $A'$ necessarily compact? If $A'$ is finite then it would be naturally true. So we need to look at cases where $A'$ is infinite. I'm not able to come up with counter-example even after looking at some sets with infinite accumulation points.

Comment: Are you assuming any separation properties?

Comment: This is completely general. Nothing is assumed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $X = \mathbb{Z}$, with the topology $\{\varnothing\} \cup \{ U \subset \mathbb{Z} : 0 \in U\}$.

The set $A = \{0\}$ is finite, hence (quasi)compact, and $A' = \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ is not compact, the open covering
$$\{ \{0,n\} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}\}$$
has no finite subcovering.

Comment: What does quasi-compact mean sir ?

Comment: Every open cover has a finite subcover. Many people call that plain "compact", but I have learned Bourbaki's terminology, which says "compact = quasicompact and Hausdorff". (Though for a singleton, that's of course moot.)

Comment: That means I have been wrong to say a topological space as compact without knowing the space is Hausdorff ?

Comment: @user710290 Only if you take Bourbaki's terminology as an unquestionable truth. More reasonably one should be aware of the fact that for many many many concepts, and then a lot more, there is more than one convention. Following a different one than your neighbour doesn't make you (nor your neighbour) wrong. Unless you are the only person following your convention maybe.

Comment: Bourbaki's quasicompact is Engelking's pseudocompact.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Oy. And how does Engelking call [pseudocompact spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space) then?

Comment: I dk. I'd have to search his book.